# Tinymce error page category in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, tinymce

I put this piece of code in my wordpress function.php.

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data' );

add_filter('edit_category_form_fields', 'cat_description');
function cat_description($tag)
{
    ?>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr class="form-field">
                <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="description"><?php _ex('Description', 'Taxonomy Description'); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                <?php
                    $settings = array('wpautop' => true, 'media_buttons' => true, 'quicktags' => true, 'textarea_rows' => '15', 'textarea_name' => 'description' );
                    wp_editor(wp_kses_post($tag->description , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 'cat_description', $settings);
                ?>
                <br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e('The description is not prominent by default; however, some themes may show it.'); ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_head', 'remove_default_category_description');
function remove_default_category_description()
{
    global $current_screen;
    if ( $current_screen->id == 'edit-category' )
    {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('textarea#description').closest('tr.form-field').remove();
        });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Tinymce you see properly.

But the text that should be showed in the "content-html" is shown in the "content-tmce".

For example:

```
"content-html": &lt;strong&gt;hello&lt;/strong&gt;

"content-tmce": <strong>hello</strong>
```

I have follow this guide: https://paulund.co.uk/add-tinymce-editor-category-description

How can I solve?

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Was it a guide? Can you link to any other resources or examples?

Comment: I follow this: https://paulund.co.uk/add-tinymce-editor-category-description

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what's bothering you here? To me it seems like it's working fine. I mean, as fine as it should...

Comment: I expect to "content-html": <strong>hello</strong>. instead to "content-tmce" preview editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is working code it may help you:

```
add_filter('edit_category_form_fields', 'edit_cat_description');

function edit_cat_description($category) { 
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(description1);?>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="description">
  <?php _ex('Description', 'Taxonomy Description'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
    <?php $settings = array('wpautop' => true, 'media_buttons' => true,'quicktags' => true, 'textarea_rows' => '15', 'textarea_name' => 'description' );

    wp_editor(html_entity_decode($category->description , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 'description1', $settings); ?>
    <br />
    <span class="description"><?php _e('The description is not prominent by default, however some themes may show it.'); ?></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'category_tinymce_css' );
function category_tinymce_css() { 
?>    
    <style type="text/css">
    .quicktags-toolbar input{float:left !important; 
     width:auto !important;}
    </style>
    <?php 
}

add_action('admin_head', 'taxonomy_tinycme_hide_description');
function taxonomy_tinycme_hide_description() {
    global $pagenow; 
    if( ($pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' || $pagenow == 'term.php' ||     isset($_GET['action']) )) :    ?>    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    $('#description, textarea#tag-description').closest('.form- field').hide();
    });
    </script><?php endif;
 }
```

Comment: It is almost correct, just that I'm two Description fields. ideas?

Comment: Means you want to implement two description fields?

Comment: solved thanks to your function: "edit_cat_description"! Thank you :)

Comment: @Matteo Enna...wel come.

Answer (score 0):

You could, without removing anything, and adding anything initialize TinyMCE on the existing textarea. First in `functions.php` enqueue admin script, I tested on Twenty Seventeen

```
/**
 * Load admin JS scripts
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function twentyseventeen_scripts_admin() {
    $js_src = includes_url( 'js/tinymce/' ) . 'tinymce.min.js';
    $css_src = includes_url( 'css/' ) . 'editor.css';

    echo '<script src="' . esc_url( $js_src ) . '" type="text/javascript"></script>';

    wp_register_style( 'tinymce_css', $css_src );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tinymce_css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/admin.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyseventeen_scripts_admin' );
```

Which is using a solution to enqueue tiny_mce manually by [myol](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176222/58895).

Then in your `admin.js` add

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    "use strict";

    if ( $('.taxonomy-category').length ) { // We're on taxonomy category screen
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : 'specific_textareas',
            selector :'#edittag #description, #tag-description'
        });
    }

});
```

[image]

[image]

You can modify the tinyMCE to your liking (plugins etc.).

Hope this helps.